# update user and user profile on same form

Tags: django, django-authentication

i created userProfile for some additional user information. here my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username

def create_user_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    u = kwargs["instance"]
    if not UserProfile.objects.filter(user=u):
        UserProfile(user=u).save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I need settings page and in this page i will update some fields of user and user profile fields at the same time. Here my forms:

```
class UpdateUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

class UpdateUserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

i have one form in my template and related function is:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    update_user_form = UpdateUserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    update_user_profile_form = UpdateUserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
    if update_user_form.is_valid() and update_user_profile_form.is_valid():
        user = update_user_form.save()
        userProfile = update_user_profile_form.save(commit=False)
        userProfile.user = user
        userProfile.save()
```

in this case i am getting "column user_id is not unique" error. why this is trying to add new user profile with this user?

what is best practice for this case?

thank you

Comment: remove `create_user_profile` function and `post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)`.

Comment: so in this case how it will create user profile when we create new user?

Comment: you create `userProfile` in `def post`  by 3 last line of this function.

Comment: yes but my intent is update this record. not to create new one.  i i tried your suggestion but i got same error.

Comment: If you're updating the profile, not creating one, you need to set the instance on the form: `update_user_profile_form = UpdateUserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)`

Comment: thank you both.  jproffitt i was trying to find a way get profile for form and your suggestion worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. In the end I opted to change my custom user model to make it inherit from AbstractUser (more info on this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) instead of linking it to User with a onetoonefield:

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
class UpdateUser(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'picture')
    template_name = 'user/edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forum:top')
```