# Django - User creates User and Profile in same form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-users

Hi have changed my view from this:
[How to make User able to create own account with OneToOne link to Profile - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470708/how-to-make-user-able-to-create-own-account-with-onetoone-link-to-profile-djan?noredirect=1#comment72087853_42470708)

For some reason the profile_form is not saving the 'user' information to the database. I have checked the information in the print(profile_form.user) data and does show the username in the terminal. It is not however saving this foreign key to the database, it just leaves it Null.

To this:
Views.py

```
class IndexView(View):
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    form = UserCreationForm
    profile_form = ProfileForm

    def post(self, request):
        user_form = self.form(request.POST)
        profile_form = self.profile_form(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile_form.user = user
            print(profile_form.user)
            print(profile_form)
            profile_form.save()

            return render(request, self.template_name)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'user_form': self.form,
                                                        'profile_form': self.profile_form})

    def get(self, request):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, self.template_name)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'user_form': self.form, 'profile_form': self.profile_form})
```

Forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    """
    A form used to create the profile details of a user.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['organisation', 'occupation', 'location', 'bio']
```

Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Comment: It might be duplicate of the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361142/update-user-and-user-profile-on-same-form

Comment: Hi that one is for updating a Profile, not to create one. I want the user to create their user account and profile in the same form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is an attribute of the *instance*, not the form.

```
    user = user_form.save()
    profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = user
    print(profile.user)
    profile.save()
```

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you! I understand! I had another form which did the same. Couldn't for the life of me see the difference.

Comment: On another note is this a good way to do this? Seems like there may be a better way to create the view.